# Snapshot testing in Flutter

Tags: snapshot, flutter, flutter-test

Similarly to Jest snapshot testing for React components, isn't there a way to "snapshot" Flutter widgets ? How would you go about implementing this ?

Comment: I think Flutter drive tests allow creating snapshots. I don't know what Jest is. See also https://flutter.io/testing/